# Ant task with argument

Tags: apache, ant

I have to configure IPV6 through Apache config.xml. I read the IP through ADDR6. I want to pass it to the command like this `- ant -f config.xml configureForIPv6 <IP>`. The target is easy to pass, but how do i pass the argument for IP? Ant does not like the arg value.

```
<ant antfile="${APACHE_HOME}/config.xml" target="configureForIPv6" arg="-DIPv6_Interface=${ADDR6}" inheritRefs="true"> ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you might [set properties from the command line](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options).

First, as for any Java application, use `-D` to define the property:

```
ant -f config.xml configureForIPv6 -DADDR=<IP>
```

Second, put the value (or values) in a Java property file (say called 'settings.txt'), content might be:

```
ADDR=<IP>
```

then read the file using the Ant `-propertyfile` option, e.g.:

```
ant -f config.xml configureForIPv6 -propertyfile settings.txt
```

Comment: When I used `-propertyfile=value` ant complained: "You must specify a property filename when using the -propertyfile argument". I had to use `-propertyfile value`

Comment: Martin Thanks, I got it running like this given below;

Inherited the property by setting it in my file itself

Thanks Praveen