# Ant rule/task that can forward a variable number of cmd line arguments to a task

Tags: ant

**I want an ant task that includes command line passed arguments.  The command line arguments can vary in number.**
Specifically, for the <java> task within ant.

I would like to do this on the command line:

```
$ ant run foo bar ...
```

Ideally, "foo" and "bar" and other arguments "...", would be passed as trailing arguments to the java instance created in the <java> task.
java would see:

```
    $ java -classpath ./output Foobar foo bar ...
```

In other words, I would like the same ant <java> task do the following:

```
$ ant run foo 
# executes "java -classpath ./output Foobar foo"

$ ant run foo bar
# executes "java -classpath ./output Foobar foo bar"

$ ant run foo bar baz
# executes "java -classpath ./output Foobar foo bar baz"
```

I imagined this might look something like :

```
<project name="Foobar" basedir=".">
    <property name="build" location="output"/>
    <target name="run" >
        <java failonerror="true" classname="Foobar" fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <dirset dir="${build}" />
            </classpath>
            <arg line="$@"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Notice the line

```
            <arg line="$@"/>
```

I imagined something like the above would pass all remaining arguments to the java instance.  (The purpose of this Question is to find that particular ant mechanism).

The methods I have seen for this [require preconfigured ant variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190399/ant-task-with-argument).  That is,

```
 $ ant run -DARG1="foo" -DARG2="bar" ...
```

But that method precludes a variable length argument list.

**Does anyone know a method for a variable number of argument that could be forwarded to an ant <java> task (preferably doesn't require writing a complex set of ant rules)?**

Answer (score 0):

That's not easy because Ant's [command line](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options) looks like this:

```
ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]]
```

That means your variable arg list `foo bar baz` items would be treated as targets, leading to similarly named Ant targets being run, or Ant throwing errors if they don't exist.

One option is to use the `-Doption=value` syntax to pass the variable argument list by means of a wrapper script.  Perhaps:

```
ant -classpath ./output -Dmy_args=\"$@\" Foobar
```

in a shell script, then make use of the passed arg in the `java` task:

```
<arg line="${my_args}"/>
```

Another option would be to write a Java main() class that will accept the arguments as you want them to be, and then call Ant for you.